# How can I copy files with specific extension in Jenkinsfile.groovy on windows slave

Tags: windows, groovy, copy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running in my Jenkinfile.groovy on windows slave, and I need to copy some files with specific extension from one folder to another.
What is the command for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo 'Copying the files to the required location'
    bat '''@echo off
    mkdir "Report Services"\\temp
    xcopy "Report Services"\\bin\\Release\\*.rdl "Report Services"\\temp
    echo 'Files copied successfully'
```